# What is the difference between pig iron and wrought iron?

Tags: iron

I mean, I know the difference in the properties.. but how are they produced? what is the difference in the method of production?

Comment: Did you search the web?

Answer (score 1):

Very little similarity except they are both mostly iron. Pig iron is from an archaic process of steel making ; The product of the blast furnace, very high carbon and silicon. Poor physical properties ,about the only direct use would be weights. Wrought iron is essentially "pure" iron, soft,ductile . Not much direct use ,it can be drawn into wire which hardens and gives it some strength. However, many products today are called wrought iron , they are actually (low) carbon steels . Today very little actual wrought iron is made ,I expect the furnace ( eg. oxygen converter )just blows oxygen ( and Argon ?) until carbon is down to 0.02 %+/-, adding no silicon or manganese. A pilot plant size operation.